# Synonym for "mom to be"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for something similar to "mom to be" / "mom expecting a child" or something similar to that which would indicate a woman going through pregnancy which is soon to be a mother.

I'm looking for a more playful / fun way of saying this, more specifically for a t-shirt print.

Comment: Baby on board is also a common playful phrase

Comment: "She has a bun in the oven." I've also seen a t-shirt with an arrow pointing to the swollen belly, and the text "Person under construction".

Answer (score 3):

***Preggers***.  You can buy a T-shirt with Preggers on it, for example [here](https://www.etsy.com/market/preggers_shirt), but there are many other choices.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preggers) says:

> British  informal
>
> (of a woman) pregnant

Comment: I have seen/heard Prego as well

Comment: @Nate W I thought Prego was a spaghetti sauce.

Comment: It is indeed , it is also a slang for pregnant:  "There are all sorts of ways to refer to a pregnant lady -- you can say she's in the family way, or that she's got a bun in the oven, or that she's sporting a baby bump. Two words that seem to have jumped into the pop culture vernacular the last few years are "prego" and "preggers."   It is also in urban dictionary.

Comment: I don't know why this is marked British. As an American, I've heard this too. (However, it is one of those words people seem to really hate.)

Comment: @Laurel  I think it was British long before it became American.  I'm neutral on preggers.  What I really hate are the -da words -- woulda, shoulda, gonna, etc ad nauseam.

Answer (score 3):

These are not nouns, however, for a t-shirt, that should not be a problem, all my examples come from [this blog by Oxford Dictionaries, called: *Pregnancy metaphors from around the world*](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/10/21/pregnancy-phrases/). The examples they cite are from different countries, they all mean *to be pregnant*, I will post the example along with the country the phrase originate from. For more information (or just out of curiosity) I recommend visiting the original blog. Here are some of the examples (not an exhaustive list):

> To have a **Bun in the oven**, from a Danish phrase
>
> To have **Bacon in the drawer**, from a French phrase
>
> To find yourself **up the pole** or **up the stick**, euphemisms from the English language
>
> Be **up the duff**, Australian English
>
> Be **up the spout**, origin not mentioned, also has other meanings (see the blog post)
>
> Be **in pig**, from the 1945 novel *The Pursuit of Love*
>
> Be **in the family way**, first uses late 17th century, no mention of origin specifically
>
> Be **stung by a serpent**, from the French phrase *être en cloque*
>
> Be **knocked up**, originally from American English, spread to other languages
>
> Be **Expectant** or of course **expecting**, no mention of origin
>
> Be **at / with hope**, Polish origin
>
> Be **in the pudding club**, also no mention of origin

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the quoted existing English or other language origin phrases (bun in the oven etc) actually refer to having been made pregnant -with several having connotations of accidental / unmarried / unwanted pregnancy- rather than being about to burst..

The slang variants (preggers) to me don’t sound very fun, although ‘prego’ means ‘please come in’ and ‘you’re welcome’ in Italian which adds some spice ;)

Maybe, looking at the t-shirt angle, you’re looking for (preferably fun) newly made up options (like the ‘child under construction’ t-shirt), or expressions referring to the birth being soon? For what it’s worth:
- delivery imminent
- baby carrier
- about to burst
- about to pop 
- head first 
- max load reached 
- help me find a name
- quick!
- you’re welcome